# Google webmaster tools: sitemaps submitted every day (?)

Tags: sitemap, google-search-console

having sent normally the first time my sitemap.xml through webmaster tools, I notice every day submitted url's plots (beside indexed ones under optimisation->sitemaps menu) without doing anything from my own. I use drupal7 with sitemap module (http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) and there's no automated tasks enabled.

Does it mean that url's are submitted "internally" by google every day? Or there's something wrong that I need to resolve?

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Google will remember any sitemaps you submit and their crawler will automatically download those and associated resources more or less whenever it feels like doing so. This is usually reflected in your Webmaster Tools. In all likelihood it'll even do so without you entering your sitemap on their website if your site gets linked to. Same goes for pretty much any other bot and crawler out in the wild.

No need to worry, everything is doing what it's supposed to. It's a Good Thing(tm) when Google crawls your site frequently :).

Comment: Feel better now ;) Thanks for clarification.